# I can't find many css references in the style.css file on Shopify.

Tags: css, web, shopify

I want to edit the class "top-labels" from the shopping cart page but I can't find it in the css stylesheet. How can I get around this?

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an A-grade modern web browser, like Chrome, Firefox or Safari. Find the developer tools for your choice. You might install Firebug for Firefox for example.

With that, right-click on the element you're interested in, say the one with the class top-labels. The browser tools will tell you exactly which CSS file contains the definition of the class, and the line number.

It cannot really be much easier. You can also change the CSS in your browser in that definition and see what the changes do, live. That is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more info but from what you've said I'd guess that the top-labels class is either located in a different style sheet or is an inline style on the page.

You could try adding the top-labels style into the stylesheet you're using and add the styles you want to it that way.